# Yahoo API for Daily Fantasy Football

Tags: api, yahoo

I've been playing around with the Yahoo API lately and can't quite figure out how to configure it to pull information from a daily fantasy football league I'm in. This is technically a contest on yahoo's site, and I've managed to get oauth2 working just fine. I figured I could pull the correct information from the league's URL which is:

```
 https://sports.yahoo.com/dailyfantasy/league/22249/3604943
```

from the documentation on yahoo API, looks like I should start with a basic URI of:

```
 https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/{game_code}.l.{league_id}
```

From what I've gathered, this should be the correct format:

```
 https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/390.l.22249
```

but this actually pulls up a regular fantasy league, not daily fantasy contest. I do know that 390 is the game code for the 2019 fantasy football league, which is the year I'm trying to pull from. Looks like 390 is maybe specific to regular fantasy football leagues and not for daily fantasy? Figured that was a good place to start from since there is historical data.

The url I posted above is for the contest history, which could be causing an issue. I went into a normal week (week 1) which here is the url:

```
 https://sports.yahoo.com/dailyfantasy/contest/5161521/
```

so I set the uri to:

```
 https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/390.l.5161521
```

and got the error:

```
 description": "There was a temporary problem with the server. Please try again shortly."
```

I keep getting this error so not quite sure where to go from here. I'm just wanting to grab some data to automate some communication out to the league. Has anyone had any success when it comes to getting the api to work specifically for daily fantasy contests? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure if you sorted this out, but you can get all the games in which you're a part of by doing a `https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/users;use_login=1/games` request.  If you don't see your daily fantasy game there, it's not possible.  I think the API only supports regular fantasy leagues though.